# how to store function string argument on the stack

Tags: arrays, c, memory, stack, heap-memory

```
void test(char arr[]){
        ;
    }
    
int main()
    {
        test("abc");

        return 0;
    }
```

`abc` is a string constant so passing it to the function will make `arr` a pointer to `"abc"` on the heap but I want it on the stack (i want to do string concatenation on it)

1. how to store `arr` on the stack
2. also does setting to `char arr[3]` or `arr[ (any size) ]` have an effect ? because my compiler allows it, and I didn't notice any.

Comment: Define a local array `char s[] = "abc";` and pass to `test`. But sounds that you might want to make it bigger for concatenation: `char s[100] = "abc";`

Comment: i could do that , but i am doing it for a challenge and the test of the challenge do it like test("abc") directly .

Comment: Then you need to do it in the function and copy the input in there. As the second method in the below answer

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @kltt accum("RqaEzty") -> "R-Qq-Aaa-Eeee-Zzzzz-Tttttt-Yyyyyyy"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of `char arr[]`, `char arr[3]`, `char arr[(any size)]` has the same meaning in function arguments. They mean `char* arr`.

The arugment (a pointer) `arr` wil typically be placed on the stack (typically on x86) or on the register (typically on x86-64), depending on the calling convension.

What you actually want to do is to put the string on the stack.

It can be done by having the caller put what to pass on the stack:

```
void test(char arr[]){
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////
}

int main()
{
    char data[102400] = "abc"; /* allocate enough space for what will be concatenated */

    test(data);

    return 0;
}
```

Or have the function copy the string.

```
#include <string.h>

void test(char arr[]){
    char data[102400];
    strcpy(data, arr);
    ;//////////////////////////////////////////
}

int main()
{
    test("abc");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks , what about the second question?

Comment: @random It won't have effect.

Comment: then why is it allowed if its usless

Comment: @random If you want a language that does not allow anything useless, then C is definitely the wrong language. ;)